# Liferay Disable AlloyUI and use Only bootstrap.css

Tags: css, liferay-6, liferay-theme

While using liferay portal 6.2,

Liferay provides both alloy ui and twitter bootstrap for ui development.

My questions -

1) Is it a good practice to use both alloy ui AND twitter bootstrap?

2) Can we disable any one of the above in Liferay so that the application uses only one css? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Is it a good practice to use both alloy ui AND twitter bootstrap?

It was designed that way in 6.2, it is a proper and recommended practice. Read [this](https://www.liferay.com/web/nathan.cavanaugh/blog/-/blogs/the-nitty-gritty-theme-improvements-and-bootstrap-in-liferay-6-6) official blog post, it should explain a lot of your doubts.

> 2) Can we disable any one of the above in Liferay so that the application uses only one css? How?

In Liferay 6.2 Bootstrap is used more for providing responsive site layouts and overall graphic design (buttons, icons, etc.). Alloy UI gives Liferay many rich dynamic JS components like calendars (Calendar portlet is based on that), diagram designers, carousel etc. Historically, Allou UI was a part of Liferay (so it was there for a longer time), and Bootstrap is available in Liferay since 6.2 but now they are tightly integrated.

Of course you can try to remove one of them (for example by creating an *_unstyled* and coding everything from scratch), but it is not recommended approach and you will definately loose much Liferay's UI OOTB functionality.